# Unusual white rectangle in tableGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

A while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511777/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-ggplot-legend-and-table) about combining a ggplot legend with a table in R to make the legend a bit more informative. The answers were very helpful and I had been using the accepted solution with no issues until recently. Now,  I've tried applying that approach to a slightly modified script and for some reason I am getting an unexpected white rectangle on top of the legend. Essentially, I make a tableGrob from a table and position it so that it is next to the ggplot legend so that they appear to be the same element. There is some other formatting that I've omitted for clarity. I've posted some example images below:

[image]

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why that rectangle is there or how to remove it. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(patchwork)

#Data
fullData <- structure(list(error = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6), prob.ed = c(0.005, 0.041, 0.298, 0.753, 0.966, 0.998, 
0.999, 0.005, 0.091, 0.598, 0.949, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 0.005, 
0.091, 0.598, 0.949, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 0.007, 0.261, 0.875, 
0.996, 1, 1, 1, 0.038, 0.568, 0.983, 1, 1, 1, 1), prob.fr = c(0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 
0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038), N = c(2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), rules = c("13SD", "13SD", 
"13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", 
"13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar")), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")

#Table for tableGrob
critTable <- structure(list(error = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7), prob.ed = c(0.192, 0.456, 
0.456, 0.77, 0.962), prob.fr = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.007, 
0.038), N = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), rules = c("13SD", "13SD-22SD", 
"13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

#ggplot
plot <- plot <- ggplot(fullData, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed, group = rules, colour = as.factor(rules))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.75, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.90, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = full.data %>%
              group_by(rules) %>%
              do({tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
                  prob.ed = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed, error))}),
            size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = full.data$error, breaks = full.data$error, expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position=c(0.93,0.2075),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.687, "cm"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12))

#tableGrob
table <- tableGrob(critTable %>%
                     select(prob.fr,
                            prob.ed,) %>%
                     rename(`Prb FR` = prob.fr,
                            `Prb ED` = prob.ed) %>%
                     mutate(Rules = ""),
                   rows = NULL,
                   theme = ttheme_minimal())

#ggplot + tableGrob
plot <- plot + inset_element(table,
                             left = 0.65, bottom = 0.2, right = 0.9, top = .3, align_to = 'full')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the code a little (added: `library(pracma)`)
changed `full.data` to `fullData` in some positions in `ggplot`. The solution is not exactly the desired output. But it should be a good start to interfere.

So the **white rectangle is caused by `ttheme_minimal` in `tableGrob`**. You can adapt with `gridExtra::ttheme_default()`.

I prefer as already suggested here [r - tableGrob background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078717/r-tablegrob-background) (but somehow newer recognized in any way) to add `theme_void()` and tweak the positions left, right, top and bottom etc...

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(patchwork)
library(pracma)
#install.packages("pracma")
#Data
fullData <- structure(list(error = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                     5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                     5, 6), prob.ed = c(0.005, 0.041, 0.298, 0.753, 0.966, 0.998, 
                                                        0.999, 0.005, 0.091, 0.598, 0.949, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 0.005, 
                                                        0.091, 0.598, 0.949, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 0.007, 0.261, 0.875, 
                                                        0.996, 1, 1, 1, 0.038, 0.568, 0.983, 1, 1, 1, 1), prob.fr = c(0.005, 
                                                                                                                      0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
                                                                                                                      0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
                                                                                                                      0.005, 0.005, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 
                                                                                                                      0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038), N = c(2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                              2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                              2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), rules = c("13SD", "13SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", "13SD-22SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar")), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")

#Table for tableGrob
critTable <- structure(list(error = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7), prob.ed = c(0.192, 0.456, 
                                                                  0.456, 0.77, 0.962), prob.fr = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.007, 
                                                                                                   0.038), N = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), rules = c("13SD", "13SD-22SD", 
                                                                                                                                           "13SD-22SD-R4SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD", "13SD-22SD-R4SD-41SD-Xbar"
                                                                                                   )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

#ggplot
plot <- ggplot(fullData, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed, group = rules, colour = as.factor(rules))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.75, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.90, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = fullData %>%
              group_by(rules) %>%
              do({tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
                         prob.ed = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed, error))}),
            size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = fullData$error, breaks = fullData$error, expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position=c(0.93,0.2075),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.687, "cm"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12))

#tableGrob
table <- tableGrob(critTable %>%
                     select(prob.fr,
                            prob.ed,) %>%
                     rename(`Prb FR` = prob.fr,
                            `Prb ED` = prob.ed) %>%
                     mutate(Rules = ""),
                   rows = NULL,
                   theme = ttheme_minimal())


#ggplot + tableGrob
plot + inset_element(table,
                     left = 0.8, bottom = 0.2, 
                     right = 0.9, top = .24, align_to = 'panel')+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved my issue. I'm curious why I didn't encounter this previously, I have used this exact code in other scripts and not seen it before. In any case, adding theme_void where you indicated fixed the problem.